# Azure AD OpenIDConnect + ASP.NET Core - Authenticate and Extra Permissions/Token?

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the following bits against my Azure AD to authenticate with ASP.NET Core.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore

I have the basic login/auth working after creating an Azure AD app. User can login/logout.

My question is given this, what's the best way when a user Auth's to log to a DB? I thought about making the redirect URL to an endpoint, saving, then just redirecting back to "Home" but is that ideal?

Also, is it possible to retrieve a bearer token via this approach? Or does this require another type of call or extending "scope"? So that for example I could retrieve the authenticated users Manager.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager

Answer (score 1):

> My question is given this, what's the best way when a user Auth's to log to a DB? I thought about making the redirect URL to an endpoint, saving, then just redirecting back to "Home" but is that ideal?

This way only able to log those who already sign-in your app successfully. It is not able to log those users who are attempt to sign-in your app but enter the wrong password.

Azure AD already provide lots of report to gain visibility into the integrity and security of your organization’s directory.( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-getting-started))

And if you are using the Azure AD Premium, you can review the sign-in activities via the [Azure new portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/) below:
[image]

And if you want to store the sign-in activity in your web app, you can write the custom code after the token is verified. Here is the code for your reference:

```
// Configure the OWIN pipeline to use OpenID Connect auth.
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
 {
            ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"],
            Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]),
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                OnTokenValidated = context => {
                    //write the custom code to store users login-in                         
                    return Task.FromResult(0); }
            },

});
```

> Also, is it possible to retrieve a bearer token via this approach?

Yes. We can get the token after receive the authorization code. You can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) to acquire the token from asp.net core app.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The OnTokenValidated code lives in my Startup.cs. Not sure how that's an ideal spot to be hitting DB

Comment: The authentication flow is start by the users, after the users enter the correct username/password Azure AD would redirect the page to the web app with the id_token. Then the OWIN component will try to verify the user information based on the id_token. And the `OnTokenValidated` will fire after the token is verified. It doesn't matter where the code lives on which class.

Comment: Is this still possible with ASP.Net Core 2.0 ? The api has changed quite a lot  .